# Paper records management software with barcodes

Tags: document-management

I'm looking for software to manage paper documents/records archive with barcodes.

We have two archive facilities with paper documents (files, folders, boxes, etc...) on shelves and our excel file is getting messed. I'm looking for recommendations for software where we can track and manage documents location with barcodes. I know a lot of organizations have such systems. It can be windows,web app or CMS witch we can adjust for such thing.

Something like *Oneil RS-SQL* or *Accutrac® Software for Records Management*, just at a littler price or open source.

My preferred requirements are (I'm looking at all options):

- Barcode scanning for registering items and tracking
- Multi user and level control
- Document ordering system.
- Document retention monitoring.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Can you please [edit] your question and include your "full" requirements? E.g. except for registering items via barcodes and assign their locations, what data must be stored? Must it be multi-user capable, remotely accessible? For more detailed hints, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) The better we know what you need, the better we can recommend :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, added requirements. I'm looking at all options.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, so it might be just me: what are "Document ordering system" and "Document retention monitoring"? Plus, what metadata must be available (which might require manual input after scan, or some automated way to be retrieved e.g. using an online service or "scanning through the document") – i.e. what "fields" must a "record" have? I already pointed at "how to ask for an alternative": Some people here might not know that Oneil software, so they cannot tell they have exactly what you need. (pointer: I'm not "grumbling" – just trying to improve your chances :)

Comment: I'm asking about paper document management system, and you have in mind electronic document management, so for you some wording does not make sense, but hope, people who works with paper document archives will understand. I'm not native on english, so wrote how I understand it.

Comment: Do you already have barcodes on all your documents? If so, then you've already got readers, and my first step would be to talk to whoever sold you the barcodes and readers.